# How does the Take() method work?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a somewhat large table I'm querying in my web app, and I only want to return *N* number of rows from the table.

I've read through the MSDN documentation, but I can't see where it states if `Take()` first pulls all of the records from the DB, or if it behaves similar to SQL Server's `TOP`.

I'm worried if `Take()` will pull all records, and **then** get the top *N* number of records OR will it behave as expected and retrieve only the *N* number of records directly

Comment: You could use SQL Profiler to see the SQL it generates for yourself. Assuming you call .Take() on an IQueryable it should perform a TOP N against SQL Server. I always use profiler to ensure that Linq-SQL / Entities generates half-decent SQL.

Comment: What `Take()` does depends on what database implementation you're using, and how you're using it. All of the common ones I've used do the right thing.

Comment: Which "LINQ" are you using? LINQ to SQL? Entity Framework?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I'm using EF & LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Those are two different things, you know?

Comment: @JohnSaunders my mistake. I'm using EF only. However, I did manage to use Nicholas' answer to print out my query. It certainly worked as expected...i.e, when I called .Take(5) it wrote SELECT TOP 5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [Return Or Skip Elements in a Sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386988(v=vs.110).aspx).

`Take(N)` will add `TOP N` to your SQL and only retrieve `N` records.

For example (using my own SQL Server 2014 with EF 6.1):

This LINQ:

```
var query = await dbContext.Lookup
                           .Where(w => w.LookupCd == '1')
                           .Take(10)
                           .ToListAsync();
```

Generates this SQL:

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
    [Extent1].[LookupId] AS [LookupId], 
    [Extent1].[LookupTypeId] AS [LookupTypeId], 
    [Extent1].[LookupCd] AS [LookupCd], 
    [Extent1].[LookupName] AS [LookupName], 
    [Extent1].[LookupDescription] AS [LookupDescription]
FROM [dbo].[Lookup] AS [Extent1]
WHERE '1' = [Extent1].[LookupCd]
```

Use the SQL Profiler (if you're using SQL Server) if you want to be sure what SQL your LINQ is generating. This is always a good practice with any LINQ you write.

[image: SQL Profiler]

Comment: I just tried printing out the var query I had written in the editor, displayed it via the Immediate Window and sure enough it printed out SELECT TOP!

Answer (score 3):

It does it as best it can.

Since you seem to be using SQL Server and its engine knows about SQL Server's having a `TOP` it will use that. It would also use this with MS Access.

If you were using PostgreSQL, MySQL or SQL Lite it would use `LIMIT`.

It might also use `"fetch first " + n + " rows only"` (DB2 and SQL:2008 standard style) or `"select first " + n + "from"` (Informix style) or `"select * from (" + restOfQuery + ") where rownum <= " + n` on Oracle or whatever a given database needed.

And if someone wrote an engine for a database that absolutely couldn't support such limits then it could indeed close the result stream after it had taken what it needed.

Either way, it does the best it can in the particular case.

It also, incidentally, uses the same approach with a value of `1` for `First()` and its variants and with a value of `2` for `Single()` and its variants (since you need to try to take at least 2 rows to test that there is only 1 to take).

Answer (score 1):

It will retrieve only the N number of records directly.

Linq:

`dbContext.table.Where(w => w.id== 1).Take(10);`

will generate the following SQL

`select top 10 * from table`

You can see the generated query using SQL Server Profile or when running under debugger, IntelliTrace shows SQL queries made.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use everytime for my gridviews paging with cool performance:

```
    resultList = context.MYTABLE.Where(WhereClause).OrderBy(orderCondition).Skip(firstItemIndex).Take(lastItemIndex - firstItemIndex + 1).ToList();
```

**WhereClause** is the WHERE part of the query (i.e.'myObj.field > 1')
**OrderBy** is clear enough I guess.
**firstItemIndex** is the value I pass to tell from which record I want to start (if my paging is **15** elements long and I call the function from page 2, the value would be 15*2 = **30** ) so we want to skip that amount of records.
The **Take** part tells how many records I want to retrieve from DB. There are different ways to do that, in my case I used a custom pager which gave me a 'maxItemIndex' computed value. So I had to substract firstItemIndex from that value to know how many records to fetch.
That way, only the specified amount of records are retrieved from the DB, which is pretty good performance.
Hope it helps

Comment: In addition to showing the code, also mind explaining why it works.